# Guacamole HTML5 RDP Gateway Trouble

Tags: server, rdp

ians!
Newby from Windows here trying to get [Guacamole] running using [this install script](https://gist.github.com/martezr/6ccb47311a42ec6d433a) . To no avail, though. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 Server and it runs through everything with the only error I see being:

```
/home/administraotr/guac_install.sh: line 174: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default: Permission denied

Failed to restart guacd.service: Unit guacd.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

/home/administrator/guac_install.sh: line 247: /etc/sysctl.conf: Permission denied.
```

Seeing as how I'm a nooby coming from Windows, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware that the version of Guacamole in the Ubuntu repositories is only 0.8.3, which is very old. If you want the latest and greatest Guacamole (currently 0.9.8), **use the instructions on the Guacamole website**: http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/installing-guacamole.html

If you are OK with a much older version, you can install the "server" using the normal sudo apt-get install

```
$ sudo apt-get install guacamole
$ sudo apt-get install guacamole-tomcat
```

Then you have to edit/configure the `user-mapping.xml` file which is found in `/etc/guacamole`. A simple user-mapping.xml that I use for RDP connectivity is the following:

```
<user-mapping>

    <!-- Per-user authentication and config information -->
    <authorize username="login-user-name" password="login-passwd">
        <connection name="name-of-server">
            <protocol>rdp</protocol>
            <param name="hostname">localhost</param>
            <param name="port">3389</param>
            <param name="color-depth">24</param>
            <param name="width">1280</param>
            <param name="height">720</param>
            <param name="enable-printing">true</param>
            <param name="enable-drive">true</param>
            <param name="drive-path">/home/login_name</param>
        </connection>
    </authorize>

</user-mapping>
```

Now... that install the Guacamole server onto your Ubuntu machine ... but if you want to see a desktop you will need to realize 1 limitation first and also understand what you need to do to finish this up.

The limitation:
Neither Ubuntu's Unity desktop nor Gnome3 will work with any remote desktop sw I am aware of.
So to have a usable desktop for "remote desktop" you should install either Mate, LXDE or XFCE.

Mate is pretty easy to use and there are lots of examples of how to install it onto whatever version of Ubuntu you are using.

For Ubuntu 14.04 here is a setup example:
http://itsfoss.com/install-mate-desktop-ubuntu-14-04/

Next you would need to install a couple more items:

freerdp...

```
$ sudo apt-get install freerdp-x11
```

and you need x11rdp on the "server" side.   The easiest way to get the very latest built/installed for you is to use a couple scripts from scarygliders:

http://scarygliders.net/2014/03/19/x11rdp-o-matic-version-3-10-released/

You will need GIT installed on your server:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
```

then use GIT to pull/copy the scaryglider "build" environment for RDP and x11RDP.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/scarygliders/X11RDP-o-Matic.git
```

change directory into X11RDP-o-Matic directory that the above GIT command copied the build packages to...

```
$ cd X11RDP-o-Matic
```

next you need to start the scarygliders "build" process.

```
$ sudo ./X11rdp-o-matic.sh --justdoit
```

NOTE:   this takes QUITE A WHILE to complete.   On my 8 core 32GB system it can take 20 minutes.

After the build is complete you have 1 more step and that is to configure the "type" of session (rdp or vnc) you want the server to use so execute the following:

```
$ sudo ./RDPsesconfig.sh
```

I know this sounds complicated or a lot of work but its not really and scarygliders script is terrific in that it takes a very complicated build process and reduces it to 1 command for you.   What you get is assurance that you are using the latest RDP and X11RDP on the server.

If all of this is done then you might want to reboot your server before trying to connect remotely with a browser by pointing the browser to the IP of the server/guacamole

so example:    192.168.1.66:8080/guacamole

Remember Tomcat uses port 8080 by default, so your firewall(s) have to permit that.

I've used Guacamole to remotely log into cloud servers and virtual machines (KVM, Virtualbox etc).   Its not perfect but it works pretty well.

Comment: Very useful thanks. Biggest thing for me was not knowing that `guacamole-tomcat` needed to be installed as well as `guacamole`

Answer (score 0):

> ... Newby from Windows here trying to get [Guacamole] running using this **install script** ...

As inviting as an install script may be, I believe that is itself the problem. When it comes to administration of a server, especially when installing software that allows other users to access your machine(s), you can't afford to take shortcuts.

It may be possible to craft an install script for a complex software stack like Guacamole, but it is all but impossible to get truly right. There are differences in server configurations, available software, etc. which can cause a simple list of commands without any tests or error handling (like the install script you're using) to fail inexplicably. As you are receiving an error running this script, I think it's safe to say that assumptions were made when the script was written, and those assumptions are invalid for your system.

I understand that, as a user of primarily Windows, you are coming from a vastly different world, but avoiding the learning curve is not the way to go. Embrace the learning curve. **Follow the [official instructions for installing Guacamole](http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/installing-guacamole.html).** Avoid the temptation to run commands without an understanding of what those commands do, let alone a whole script full of them. If you encounter problems along the way, ask questions about those specific problems. You will be far better off in the long run.